# MySQL install script doesn't run?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, module, database

I am trying to make a custom module in magento 1.8.1 and I am following the tutorial given [here](http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-developper-guide-howto-tutorial-5)

I found everything fantastic except that in this tutorial, the author is creating the table directly in the database, so if I move this module to another setup I have to create the table manually in the database, which I don't want to do. And also there is no entry for the module in the `core_resource` and `core_config_data` tables.

Now when I am trying to create the installer file in the `sql` folder of my custom module it is not running and shows an error

```
a:5:{i:0;s:102:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table'demo_magento_dummy.pfay_test' doesn't exist";i:1;s:4361:"#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_new/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_new/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_new/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_new/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_new/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_new/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_new/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_new/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
```

and here is my `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php`

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pfay_test;
CREATE TABLE `pfay_test` (
`id_pfay_test` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
 `nom` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `prenom` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `telephone` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

I checked the version of the module to see if it is the problem of version but version are same and I am not able to understand what is the problem here.

So here is my `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

 <modules>
    <Pfay_Test>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Pfay_Test>
 </modules>

 <frontend>
   <routers>
      <routeurfrontend>
          <use>standard</use>
          <args>
             <module>Pfay_Test</module>
             <frontName>test</frontName>
          </args>
       </routeurfrontend>
   </routers>

   <layout>
       <updates>
           <test>
              <file>test.xml</file>
          </test>
       </updates>
   </layout>
</frontend>

<admin>
   <routers>
   <test>
      <use>admin</use>
      <args>
      <module>Pfay_Test</module>
      <frontName>admintest</frontName>
      </args>
   </test>
   </routers>    
</admin>

<adminhtml>
   <layout>
       <updates>
       <test>
     <file>test.xml</file>
       </test>
   </updates>
   </layout>
   <menu>
  <test translate="title" module="adminhtml">
      <title>My Plugins</title>
      <sort_order>100</sort_order>
      <children>
     <set_time>
         <title>Address Book</title>
         <action>admintest/adminhtml_index</action>
     </set_time>
      </children>
  </test>
   </menu>
</adminhtml>

<global>
   <blocks>
       <test>
          <class>Pfay_Test_Block</class>
       </test>
   </blocks>

   <models>
   <test>
      <class>Pfay_Test_Model</class>
      <resourceModel>test_mysql4</resourceModel>        
   </test>
   <test_mysql4>
      <class>Pfay_Test_Model_Mysql4</class>
      <entities>
        <test>
        <table>pfay_test</table>
        </test>
      </entities>
   </test_mysql4>
   </models>

<!-- allow the plugin to read and write -->

   <resources>

       <test_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Pfay_Test</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </test_setup> 
<!-- connection to write -->

   <test_write>
       <connection>
         <use>core_write</use>
       </connection>
   </test_write>
<!-- connection to read -->

   <test_read>
       <connection>
         <use>core_read</use>
       </connection>    
   </test_read>
   </resources>
</global>
```

Comment: Do not hardcode the table name. Maybe you tables are using some prefix. Always use $installer->getTable(). Read more here : http://codegento.com/2011/02/install-scripts-and-upgrade-scripts/ and here http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources

Comment: Can you post your module's config.xml here?

Comment: can you post the config.xml of your module and the path to the install script?

Comment: So any solution now, I really need a help with this

Comment: The config looks ok. Make sure you placed the install script in `sql/test_setup/install-0.1.0.php`

Comment: my file is in the same directory as you mention but its name is `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` is this causing any problem

Comment: http://geeksterminal.com/how-to-fix-error-sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not-found/554/

Comment: Rename your script as `install-0.1.0.php`

Comment: I tried that already, but nothing is happening. I really don't understand what is the issue here. What I am doing wrong. I am using magento 1.8.1 and xampp 1.8.3-2 in ubuntu

Comment: I tested your code. It worked after doing these simple modifications. Simply put the closing tag for `<config>` node in the `config.xml`. And rename the script as `install-0.1.0.php`. This should work

Comment: I had the closing tag for `<config>` in my file, it is a typo over here, and I tried renaming the file, but still no luck with that.

Comment: I think my installer file is not running either way, when I paste the `die` action at the start of file, nothing happens it still loads the page in frontend and backend both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `{$installer->getTable('test/test')}`;
CREATE TABLE `{$installer->getTable('test/test')}` (
`id_pfay_test` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
 `nom` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `prenom` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 `telephone` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 2):

Following are the possible reasons for not running your module sql script

1. Open the database and check in core_resource table, Find your
   module setup record like `"customlink_setup"` and delete that record if
   you found and try again.
2. Open the database and check in eav_attribute table, Find your
   attribute ID like `"thumbnail_link"` in table and delete it if you
   found.
3. Check your module version in `config.xml` file and mysql installer
   file version number must be same

I Hope It will help you

Code taken from this link http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2015/09/magento-my-module-extension-sql.html